# MySQL Select statement with datetime

Tags: mysql, select

I have this MySQL SELECT statment that works for me, but I would like to improve it by a bit :

```
SELECT event.id_event, event_title, event_details, event_date_time, event_showtime.id_show, event_category.id_category, ( 6371 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS(  '49.20513921227407' ) ) * COS( RADIANS( event_showtime.latitude ) ) * COS( RADIANS( event_showtime.longitude ) - RADIANS(  '18.762441839599678' ) ) + SIN( RADIANS(  '49.20513921227407' ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( event_showtime.latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM event
JOIN event_showtime ON event.id_event = event_showtime.id_event
JOIN event_category ON event.id_category = event_category.id_category
HAVING distance <  '5'
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 0 , 20
```

This returns a set of 3 rows :

```
id_event    event_title event_details   event_date_time id_show id_category distance
1   Testovacia na FRI   Testovacia udalosť na FRI   2014-04-01 20:00:00 2   1   0.390327906350887
1   Testovacia na FRI   Testovacia udalosť na FRI   2014-03-31 16:13:17 1   1   0.390327917895938
2   Čin-Čin Čin-Čin je nádherný poetický príbeh o dospievaní. ...   2014-03-31 15:00:00 3   2   1.02364018489261
```

This is basically a set of eventshowtimes in location. But the trick is in the result, I would only like to see one result of event with id = 1 that has the date time most closest to NOW(). Is this possible ?

Edit: this is the content of event_showtime table :

```
INSERT INTO `event_showtime` (`id_show`, `id_event`, `latitude`, `longitude`, `event_date_time`) VALUES
(1, 1, 49.2016762922894, 18.7615620750428, '2014-03-31 16:13:17'),
(2, 1, 49.2016762922894, 18.7615620750428, '2014-04-01 20:00:00'),
(3, 2, 49.2113914818564, 18.7520992416382, '2014-03-31 15:00:00'),
(4, 2, 49.0545135142313, 20.2952223676682, '2014-04-16 11:00:00'),
(5, 2, 49.2113914818564, 18.7520992416382, '2014-04-23 11:00:00'),
(6, 2, 49.0545135142313, 20.2952223676682, '2014-04-30 11:00:00'),
(7, 2, 49.2016762922894, 18.7615620750428, '2014-04-29 12:00:00'),
(8, 1, 49.2016762922894, 18.7615620750428, '2014-04-24 12:00:00');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT id_event , event_title, event_details, event_date_time, id_show, id_category,  distance FROM(
SELECT event.id_event id_event, event_title, event_details, max(event_date_time) event_date_time, max(event_showtime.id_show) id_show, event_category.id_category id_category, ( 6371 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS(  '49.20513921227407' ) ) * COS( RADIANS( event_showtime.latitude ) ) * COS( RADIANS( event_showtime.longitude ) - RADIANS(  '18.762441839599678' ) ) + SIN( RADIANS(  '49.20513921227407' ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( event_showtime.latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM event
JOIN event_showtime ON event.id_event = event_showtime.id_event
JOIN event_category ON event.id_category = event_category.id_category
GROUP BY event.id_event
HAVING distance <  '5'
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 0 , 20
  )t
```

Comment: Ing update it at home. Yea it should be 7 there i think

Comment: Well I am sorry :/ but still now luck I have to unmark your answear. I have updated my search query with different latitude and longitude : http://pastebin.com/eJ6yFDgD I have updated pastebin ... thank you for your time

Comment: + I dont want max from date I want lowest date from dates > NOW() just noticed what you had there

Comment: + looking at yours result, id show 7 does not have date proper datetime like in the insert statment

Comment: Those dates should be like this probably SELECT event_showtime.id_event, min(event_date_time) as edt FROM event_showtime
WHERE event_showtime.event_date_time > NOW()
GROUP BY id_event

Comment: i guess like this: `CASE WHEN event_date_time > NOW() THEN min(event_date_time) ELSE max(event_date_time) END as event_date_time` But i didnt try it. you have to try, sorry i must go sleep now.

Comment: I really dont know how to implement case statement :) but Ill give it a look :) thank you anyways have a good night :)

Comment: like that: select  name , CASE ........ end as datetime , country , age  from ...

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6545ab/124 here is something I want to achive, but here I want to have only row 1 and 3 as results, plus to add more stuff, as title and more ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort them according to `event_date_time` descending, then add limit 1:

```
SELECT event.id_event, event_title, event_details, event_date_time, event_showtime.id_show, event_category.id_category, ( 6371 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS(  '49.20513921227407' ) ) * COS( RADIANS( event_showtime.latitude ) ) * COS( RADIANS( event_showtime.longitude ) - RADIANS(  '18.762441839599678' ) ) + SIN( RADIANS(  '49.20513921227407' ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( event_showtime.latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM event
JOIN event_showtime ON event.id_event = event_showtime.id_event
JOIN event_category ON event.id_category = event_category.id_category
HAVING distance <  '5'
ORDER BY event_date_time DESC
LIMIT 1
```

A few questions though - why would you add order by distance and limit 0,20 if you are only expecting one record? Or do you mean to get only the latest event_date_time for EACH id? If so, you need to get the `MAX(event_date_time)` and `id_event` for all records, then join this to you outside table

```
SELECT event.id_event, event_title, event_details, event_date_time
FROM event
JOIN event_showtime ON event.id_event = event_showtime.id_event
JOIN event_category ON event.id_category = event_category.id_category
JOIN (SELECT MAX(event_date_time) as dt, id_event from event) inner_t
    ON inner_t.id_event = event.id_event
    AND inner_t.dt = event.event_date_time
WHERE distance <  '5'
```

Comment: Thank you :) I figured that out already, and yes the option number 2 was the right one, I had it somehow different but the point is the same :)

Comment: Well, to be sure I still have some problems :/ Here is my situation : I have table named event, that has event details and table event_showtime where are the details about event played, like datetime, location and so. So one event cant be played today, and also tomorrow in the same location. My select from top would return 2 rows, but I want to return only one row that would have date of today and on tomorow will have date with tomorow. But if the show will be played on 31st of april and I will be runnign select in 3 days I want it to show me date of 31. :) Hope you will understand

Comment: Can you give me the result you are getting now?

And then give me the result that you want to have?